# DataGrid doesn't expand properly on screen resize

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, resize

I want my `DataGrid` to take up all the available space in the Window that's available. However, it doesn't entirely do so:

[Not maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjvaq.png)
[Maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQHAR.png)

(Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to embed pictures, so StackOverflow's put a link to it instead)

This is my entire Windows' XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BPS.View.MainView"
        x:Name="MainViewWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BPS.View"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Title="{Binding WindowTitle}"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Height="539.2" Width="768">

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" IsEnabled="{Binding MainGridIsEnabled}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="MainDataGrid"
                  cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseRightButtonUp] = [Action DataGridRightMouseClickEvent($eventArgs)]"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MainGridItemsSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,23,10.6,-477.6"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=id}" Width="Auto" Header="ID" CanUserResize="True"
                                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=name}" Width="Auto" Header="Name"
                                    CanUserResize="True" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=age}" Width="Auto" Header="Age"
                                    CanUserResize="True" IsReadOnly="True" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I didn't do anything further aside from these attributes (supposed to do maximize the DataGrid in fullscreen mode) in the DataGrid. What do I lack?

Comment: What is the container of your `DataGrid` (the outer element that contains the `DataGrid`)?

Comment: @MohammadDehghan It's a Grid. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `DataGrid` directly in the root `Grid` element of the window and remove the margins.

Then it will fill the entire window. You can confirm this by setting the `Background` property of the `DataGrid`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MainDataGrid"
              Background="Green"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MainGridItemsSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=id}" Width="Auto" Header="ID" CanUserResize="True"
                                IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=name}" Width="Auto" Header="Name"
                                CanUserResize="True" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=age}" Width="Auto" Header="Age"
                                CanUserResize="True" IsReadOnly="True" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I did this, nothing changed. When I removed the margins, it is somehow stuck in the very top almost outside of the window.

Comment: Post the markup of your entire window then if you want someone to be able to point out what you are doing wrong...

Comment: I did this in the main post. Please check this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about the `DataGrid`, because its `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` are set to `Stretch` by default and `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` (in your Xaml) play no part in *arranging* the `DataGrid`.

First, should see the type of the container of the `DataGrid`. If it is something such as a `StackPanel` or a `DockPanel`, this is the problem. Change them. However, it it is something such as a `Grid`, `DockPanel`, `Border`, `Window`, ... you should check their properies (HorizontalAlignments and etc.) and also their containers.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce your problem is when I set Margin="10,23,10.6,+477.6" (note the + sign). Make sure this is not the case. Sorry